# How can I make a String Base64 Url Safe Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, base64

I've been trying for a while but I can't seem to get my string to be Url Safe no matter what I do:

```
Input: XwPp9xazJ0ku5CZnlmgAx2Dld8SHkAeT+d7yvxw=
Desired Output: XwPp9xazJ0ku5CZnlmgAx2Dld8SHkAeT-d7yvxw
```

Essentially I want to apply some flags on my input string from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html, namely `Base64.URL_SAFE`,`Base64.NO_PADDING` and `Base64.NO_WRAP`. However when I do:

```
String str = "XzbeW3jg9NYp6J0w2mTP4NLrTK06p1EDTnNG+KYhvyw=";

byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(
        str.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);

byte[] strBytes = Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
String decoded = new String(strBytes);

//outputs original str "XzbeW3jg9NYp6J0w2mTP4NLrTK06p1EDTnNG+KYhvyw="
System.out.println(decoded);
```

I am not sure why the url safe encoding isn't working here, is there something I"m doing wrong? Is there a way I can get my desired output (besides manually doing `String.replace()` and other string modifications?

Comment: You encoded something into b64 and then decoded it back - works as expected. But you already have encoded input, you should have decoded it with url-unsafe decoded and then encoded the real "plain text" with url-safe encoder.

Comment: Why are you Base64 encoding an already encoded string? Since input is already Base64 encoded, you *first* decode it, *then* re-encode it using the options you want. Flip the calls to `encode()` and `decode()`, and don't convert the intermediate `byte[]` to/from string.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for the comments everyone! It was correct that I already had a base64 encoded string and I needed to decode first then re-encode.

```
byte[] strBytes = Base64.decode(str, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(
    strBytes, Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
return new String(encoded);
```

is the solution that ended up working for me.